# FancyBox 2 + IE8 / Chrome - Fails to work

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint-2007, fancybox, fancybox-2

Good afternoon!

I need some help here. I've been beating my head against the wall here and can't figure out why fancybox won't work. I am trying to load some iframes with some links and have them show up in a fancybox.

I am using the default includes from fancybox.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you for taking a look at this.

Ross

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>   
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>   
<link type="css/test" rel="stylesheet" href="/source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen"/>   
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();    
    });      
</script>     
<a class="fancybox fancybox-iframe" href="/Contact.html">
```

Answer (score 1):

Is not working in IE because your document is running in quirks mode. fancybox needs standards mode to work properly with IE.

Your current `DOCTYPE` declaration is (as in your code above)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

and I guess it should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

(you missed to close the `DOCTYPE` declaration properly .... unless is a typo)

Additionally, change this line:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox-iframe" href="/Contact.html">
```

into this :

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="/Contact.html"> ...</a>
```

... or :

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="/Contact.html"> ...</a>
```

... also make sure you are closing your `<a>` tags properly

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the script to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#featured").fancybox({
      'hideOnContentClick': true,
      'transitionIn'        : 'none',
      'transitionOut'       : 'none',
      'type'                : 'iframe'
    });
});
```

And then use:

```
 <a id="featured" href="/Contact.html">
```

Comment: A step in the right direction! It now works in Chrome but not IE8. Any ideas as to why? It looks like it tries to load it but fails.

Comment: Hmph... What happens when you just call: $.fancybox("<p>hello</p>"); on document ready for IE8?

Comment: Also, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.8.2.min.js and where do I add the $.fancybox("<p>hello</p>"); ? I am just getting into JQuery.

Comment: It's cool. Just put that above the $("a#featured").fancybox({... line. Like make it the first command within the $(document).ready(function(){ line. What it should do is immediately open up a fancybox with "hello" in it.

Comment: It works in Chrome but not IE. It's like something is preventing it from running.

Comment: Is Javascript enabled on it? Open Internet Explorer and try this:
Tools > internet options > security > custom level...
Find "Active Scripting", then check enable.

Comment: I actually can't check to do security protocols on this PC but I have a javascript text rotator on the same page and use jquery to change a class. Also this used to work but broke suddently.

Comment: The text rotator broke or the fancybox broke? Either way, can you post up any other scripts you have running on the page? I'm curious if it's causing any issues.

Comment: Will do. The text rotator still works it was just FancyBox that broke. I also removed the rotator thinking that it was the problem and it didn't fix FancyBox.

Comment: Can't add it until 7 more hours apparently. The code that is. But I did remove it and the problem with FancyBox still exists. It also doesn't work in IE7.

Comment: @VuNguyen : the OP is using fancybox v2.x (see the tags) and you are proposing a solution with invalid API options.